# How do I print out the values after GroupBy()?

Tags: c#

I have a problem, I am trying to figure out how to print out the value after I am done grouping my array.

I have figured out how to print out the Key of the "object" but how do I print out the value?

I know that it is supposed to look like {key: value}: {1: [1], 2: [2, 2], 3: [3, 3], 4: [4]}.

But I only manage to print out the keys in my code below, => 1-, 2-, 3-, 4-
Any advice is greatly appreciated.

```
public static void figureModeOut(int[] source)
    {
      int[] numbers1 = { 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4 };

      var step1 = numbers1.GroupBy(x => x);

      foreach (var item in step1)
      {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} -", item.Key);
      }
}
```

Comment: A GroupBy produces a two dimensional array [key][items].  So try following change : Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", item.Key, string.Join(",", item.Select(x => x.ToString())));  I like using the string join method to combine array items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The returned `IGrouping<TKey, TElement>` (i.e. each `item` in `step1`) itself is the `IEnumerable<TElement>` containing the sequence of values for any given `TKey`, so just use `string.Join()` on each `item` to print out it's values:

```
foreach (var item in step1)
{
    // composite formatting:
    Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", item.Key, string.Join(",", item));
    // ..or using string interpolation:
    Console.WriteLine($"{item.Key} - {string.Join(",", item)}");
}
```

Output:

> 1 - 1
>
> 2 - 2,2
>
> 3 - 3,3
>
> 4 - 4

Answer (score 0):

the values are the item itself.
just use

```
item.ToList()
```

And you will see the elemnts.

you can do any linq operation on item

here is the full code:

```
public static void figureModeOut(int[] source)
{
    int[] numbers1 = { 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4 };
    var step1 = numbers1.GroupBy(x => x);
     foreach (var item in step1)
     {
         foreach (var element in item)
         {
             Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", item.Key, element);
          }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like the others, I would advise doing the same things unless I would ensure that you do not need to use `item.ToList()` or `item.Select(...)` (for `string.Join`).

`IGrouping<TKey, TElement>` produce by LINQ `GroupBy` produces an `IEnumerable<TElement>` with `TKey Key` property in it. So, the item is iterable itself. You can use it as following in `string.Join(sep, collection)` or whatever.
Also to see the results in debugging you do not need conversion.

I would also add, that `ToList` or ToAnyOther mutable collection is not what you want as it is about a violating concept, IMHO.

Well, just iterate over the item you have.